# Basic CGI Example Help in Python

Tags: python, cgi

I'm working through Programming Python and am trying to work through the basic CGI example. I so far have the following files saved in the same directory (titled: cgi101.html and webserver.py respectively):

```
<html>
<title>Interactive Page</title>
<body>
    <form method=POST action="cgi-bin/cgi101.py">
        <p><b>Enter your name:</b>
        <p><input type=text name=user>
        <p><input type=submit>
    </form>
</body>
```

```
import os, sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

webdir = '.'
port = 8080

os.chdir(webdir)
srvraddr = ("", port)
srvrobj = HTTPServer(srvraddr, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
srvrobj.serve_forever()
```

Then in a sub directory titled cgi-bin I have the following script called cgi101.py saved:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print('Content-type: text/html\n')
print('<title>Reply Page</title>')
if not 'user' in form:
    print('<h1>Who are you?</h1>')
else:
    print('<h1>Hello <i>%s</i>!</h1>' % cgi.escape(form['user'].value))
```

I then follow these steps:

1. Run webserver.py from the directory where webserver.py and cgi101.html are located
2. Navigate to http://localhost:8080/cgi101.html this opens up as expected
3. When I enter a name and submit, initially I get an error saying the cgi script is not executable. If I go to cgi101.py and then run chmod 744  to make it executable, when I repeat the above steps the following URL renders: http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/cgi101.py but no content renders whatsoever and the command line where I ran the server gives a FileNotFound error.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Richard

Comment: first: CGI is very old technic and currently probably nobody use it. Better learn web framework like Flask, Django, Bottle.

Comment: BTW: as I know server can run CGI script only from folder `cgi-bin` but not from `subfolder/cgi-bin` so better use absolute url `/cgi-bin/cgi101.py` in html. If you use relative url (without `/` at the beginning) then file `subfolder/index.html` may try to run `subfolder/cgi-bin/cgi101.py`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you get error 404 or 403 ?

Comment: you may have to set executable for folder too, `chmod u+x cgi-bin`. After setting `+x` for folder and for file I have no problem to run it.